# How does one intuitively think of topological connectedness? (And in particular, in comparison to path-connectedness.)

Tags: general-topology, intuition, connectedness

I encounter the topological notion of connectedness quite often lately, but I don't really have a good intuitive picture of it. **How does one think of connectedness intuitively?**

To provide some context, I do, in contrast, have an intuitive picture of *path-connectedness*. It simply makes sense to me to say that a space is (path-) connected whenever every two points can be connected by a path. Why then is the notion of connectednes prefered over path-connectedness? Is this only because of technical advantages (in the sense that they make it possible to prove more theorems), or is there also an intuitive motivation to extend the notion of path-connectedness to connectedness? And what are typical situations where this difference plays an important role, given the fact that for subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb C^n$, for instance, the two notions are (EDIT: often) equivalent?

Comment: Connectedness is typically useful to argue for clopen sets being either $\varnothing$ or the entire space. For instance, one often uses it to show that certain maps must be constant. Also note that, in most "intuitive" spaces, the two notions of connectedness and path-connectedness coincide.

Comment: Connectedness and path-connectedness are *not* equivalent in $\Bbb R^n$ or $\Bbb C^n$ (consider the topologist's sine curve).

Comment: @Clayton I think you mean there are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$ in which they are not equivalent.  The spaces themselves  are both connected and path-connected.

Comment: @N.Owad: You are right, both $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb C^n$ are simultaneously path-connected and connected, but this doesn't make the definitions equivalent.

Comment: I intuitively picture a disconnected space as a collection of 2 or more disjoint bubbles with empty space (vacuum) between them . The bubbles are non-empty pair-wise disjoint open sets.... Connectedness is not stronger than path-connectedness. It is weaker. In the real  plane the subpace  $(\{0\}\times [-1,1])\;\cup \;\{(x,\sin (1/x): x\in (0,1]\}$ ( called The Topologists' Sine Curve) is connected but not path-connected.